# Magento Import Product Images Media via CSV

Tags: database, magento, entity-attribute-value

Is it necessary to set the attributes **_media_image** with **_media_attribute_id** in the CSV to be uploaded?

All images are stored in CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY and the thumbnail, image and small_image in CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR right? According to the CSV column format

> sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail,
>   thumbnail_label

the images will only registered in CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_VARCHAR against the EAV attributes_id's of **image, small_image and thumbnail**. And so, the images are visible on front-end product_list page (as thumbnail) and product_view page (as product image).

But when we go into the product options via admin Catalog > Manage Product and than click a product and then Images tab on the left side, there will be no images. The reason is that, the images are not in the "CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY" and with the new updated result to be saved, Magento sends no image for base, small and thumbnail images. This results the loss of image when we edit anything of product from admin.

Note: I uploaded the images to magento_root/media/catalog/import/. And, Currently I'm working on Magento 1.9.0.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following CSV format for importing images in Magento 1.9 and above doesn't work

> sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail,
>   thumbnail_label

You must have to specify the **_media_attribute_id** and **_media_image** attribute. Without using these two attributes, you cannot import images properly. So the right CSV format for images import is as follow:

```
sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail, thumbnail_label,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable
```

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_0c_P3tX48o5gsR2Lj3y_-ez02UVZS_u-8PkuhFRwc/edit?usp=sharing) to see the right csv file for Images import

*Note: Make sure the images are placed in the magento_root/media/import/ folder. Otherwise Magento could not Import the images.*

For more information, visit this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=170)

Comment: So man if i want to use this method and i want to pass the images as urls, it will work or what ?! and how we can make it work if not ?!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest try using Magmi, a very easy and cool extension to upload product images or update/add any product content.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

It has detailed documents as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is not the answer of my question.